# Create a SP 2013 site through the REST API via Jquery AJAX

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a SP 2013 site through the REST API via Jquery AJAX. I have extracted the REQUEST_DIGEST from the '/_api/contextinfo' call. Next, while trying to set the X-RequestDigest header for the '/_api/web/webinfos/add' call ,a pre-flight request with method 'OPTIONS' is sent by the browser which is getting a HTTP 403 response code. As per my understanding , it is expecting the FedAuth cookie , while the browser, according to the CORS principle is not sending the authentication info. It seems that the 'OPTIONS' verb need to be configured on the SP 2013 and I have not found any clear solution for this. Is my understanding correct , in which case can anyone provide a solution ?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a site collection or a subsite inside an existing site collection?

Comment: I am trying to create subsite inside an existing sitecollection using site template.

Answer (score 0):

I created this code that works on my Sharepoint 2013 environment.

First, I try my ajax request with a relative URL like this : `/_api/web/webinfos/add`

The resquest result in a **403 Forbidden**.

Then I retry with : `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add"`

and this time it works fine.

The reason is that my site collection URL pattern is :

- http://domain/manage-path/site-collection

So when I use a relative URL **/_api/web/webinfos/add** its the same as using :

- http://domain/_api/web/webinfos/add

Because its not the address of the current site collection Sharepoint returns a Cross-Site Scripting error.

But When I use **_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add"** it give me the full URL of the site collection :

- http://domain/manage-path/site-collection/_api/web/webinfos/add

Here is the complete script :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function createSubsiteUsingREST(data,siteTitle,siteUrl,siteDescription) {

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'parameters': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation'
                },
                'Url': siteUrl,
                'Title': siteTitle,
                'Description': siteDescription,
                'Language': 1033,
                'WebTemplate': 'sts',
                'UseUniquePermissions': true
            }
        }),
        success:function(){
            alert('SubSite Created with success!');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('oups! An error occured during the process of creating this new SubSite!');
        }           
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnCreateSubSiteWithREST').on('click',function() {
        var siteTitle = $('#txtSiteTitle').val();
        var siteUrl = $('#txtSiteUrl').val();
        var siteDescription = $('#txtSiteDescription').val();
        createSubsiteUsingREST(siteTitle,siteUrl,siteDescription);
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnCreateSubSiteWithREST" value="Create New SubSite Using REST">

<div><label>Title of the SubSite : </label><input type="text" id="txtSiteTitle"></div>
<div><label>URL of the SubSite : </label><input type="text" id="txtSiteUrl"></div>
<div><label>Description of the SubSite : </label><input type="text" id="txtSiteDescription"></div>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am using the absoluteUrl and I think I forgot to mention that the call is being generated from outside the sharepoint server / from a web application on a different domain as a result it is a cross-domain call . We have used the crossDomain parameters on the call but due to the custom header (X-RequestDigest) a prefetch request is being generated which is being denied(403). We need a way to configure SP to accept the OPTIONS request and send a HTTP 200 back.